# Diferença entre os métodos fetch e setFetchMode da PDO

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, pdo

Eu entendi a diferença entre fetch e fetchAll, mas agora, qual é a diferença entre esses e o setFetchMode? Parece que é a mesma coisa... (na hora de montar pelo menos).

Posso fazer com os dois assim:

```
fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

e

```
setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 4):

Opcionalmente `fetch()` e `fetchAll()` podem ter o formato de retorno alterado do padrão definido passando a respectiva constante como argumento. Sua vantagem é usar um formato diferente do padrão em um ponto específico do código sem que isso interfira em outras partes.

[`setFetchMode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php) define direto no PDOStatement o formato padrão de retorno ou seja todas as chamadas de `fetch()/fetchAll()` vão obedecer essa configuração.

Outra forma de definir o formato padrão é através do construtor informando um valor para `ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE` como no exemplo abaixo:

```
$options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=vendas;', 'root', '', $options);
```

O mesmo resultado é obtido com o método [`setAttribute()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)

Answer (score 3):

Na PDO, o método `setFetchMode` é utilizado para definir o modo como os dados são obtidos, no caso do exemplo que você postou, a constante `PDO::ASSOC` é utilizada para retornar os dados em um array associativo.

Os métodos `fetch/fetchAll` com o parâmetro `PDO::ASSOC` irão obter os dados de uma query em um array associativo (pois utiliza a constante em questão), nesse caso o próprio método está especificando diretamente como os dados serão retornados. Geralmente, isso só é necessário quando a PDO não foi configurada previamente com o `setFetchMode`.

No caso de um tipo de retorno ser configurado com `setFetchMode`, o parâmetro passado para o `fetch/fetchAll` não é mais preciso. Ou seja, o método `setFetchMode` deixa configurado a forma padrão de obter os dados para não ter que especificar isso depois.